# Azure Site Recovery VM in VMWare 6.0 erroneously says it does not have internet connectivty

Tags: azure, azure-networking

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW1Bo.png)[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSpNQ.png)

Setting up the Azure Site Recovery VM in VMWare 6.0 to enable replication between on-prem and Azure.

Azure Site Recovery Configuration Manager says "Checking for internet connectivity failed"

"Unable to connect to Azure Site Recovery using the given settings.  Either the proxy details provided are incorrect, or the proxy server/firewall is blocking your request to access Azure Site Recovery URLs.  Ensure that the following URLs are allowed through your proxy server/firewall."

[Https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/)
*.blob.core.windows.net

I tested the dev.mysql.com address and I can reach that address no problem.  I can reach any other web page no problem.  Except I don't understand the syntax for *.blob.core.windows.net...  What am I supposed to replace the '*' with the test this address?

What do I need to do to establish connectivity to Azure in this case?  What troubleshooting might you suggest? I have a site to site VPN to Azure that is already working, that I use to send backups to Azure storage.

When I test unitedway.blob.core.windows.net, I get the message "the account being access does not support http.
[[image: http not supported msg]]

When I try the IP address for the unitedway.blob.core.windows.net, I get a message "The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server"

[image: URI does not represent resource]

When I test https://unitedway.blob.core.windows.net, I get a message 'Value for one of the query parameters specified is invalid.

[image: value for query parameter invalid]

Comment: Have tried multiple web browsers, both from Vmware console and from remote desktop console, restarted Windows.  turned off IE Enhanced Security Configuration

Comment: If you're using a URL-based firewall proxy to control outbound connectivity, allow access to these [URLs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-enable-replication#outbound-connectivity-for-urls)used by Site Recovery. Please let me know if this work.

Comment: I'll take a close look the logs for the Sonicwall and try accessing those sites again to see if the Sonicwall is blocking them.  Usually if the Sonicwall is blocking a site, it will say "Sonicwall blocked access to this site" on the resulting web page.  I am guessing perhaps I made an error somewhere in configuration on the Azure side or setup of the Site Recovery VM, but not sure yet.  We'll see.

Comment: I look at firewall logs regularly, and firewall is not blocking these web sites.  I will post images of what I am seeing when trying to connect to *.blob.core.windows.net

Comment: It's possible I made a very basic mistake in setting up Azure Site Recovery VM, just not sure what that is yet.

Comment: Can you confirm if you check `connect directly without a proxy` under the [modify proxy settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/physical-manage-configuration-server#modify-proxy-settings) configuration panel?

Comment: I am not using a proxy, and have the setting "use proxy to connect to the internet" set to "no"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4033999/how-to-resolve-azure-site-recovery-agent-issues-after-disabling-tls-1

To fix these issues, make sure that the .NET Framework 4.6 or a later version is installed and TLS 1.2 is enabled as the default protocol. To enable TLS 1.2, follow these steps:

1. Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.
2. At the elevated command prompt, run the following command: 
   *net stop obengine*
3. Start Registry Editor, and then navigate to the following registry subkeys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \Software\Microsoft.NETFramework

4. Under each of these registry keys, locate the subkeys that indicate a version.

Note These subkeys appear in the "v" format.

5. For each of these subkeys, add a DWORD Value that is named SchUseStrongCrypto, and set its value to 1. Repeat step five for all the subkeys that have the "v" format.
6. Exit Registry Editor.
7. At an elevated command prompt, run the following command:
   *net start obengine*

After you complete these steps, you should be able to install and use Azure Site Recovery as expected.